# Phrase for doing something unexpectedly fast

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to know if there is such a phrase. What I mean is doing something "over the course of a night", but of course it doesn't have to be that short.

I think it could have something to do with things which ended unexpectedly fast, you did it in unbelieveably short period of time. This is a phrase from another language, I didn't want to translate it in a plain way. I hope there is something similar in English.

Comment: _Damn that was fast_

Comment: Some more details could help. How formal should it end up sounding? What sort of phrase/part of speach should it be. "I blinked and he was done." would be informal, descriptive, and conversational, for example.

Comment: [One-minute man.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cy22Woq_Ls)

Comment: as @Sphero states in his answer, `overnight` is used the exact same way in American English at least. *"He/She was an overnight success"* means they had success extremely quickly and sometimes implies that it was unexpected by the speaker.

Comment: Jarrod you're right. It was a political context, let's say to overthrow some seemingly strong government, or destroy a system, that kind of situation, but to do it in a matter of days, contrary to expectations. My bad I didn't provide details, but I ''overnight'' seems like a good choice.

Answer (score 19):

[Overnight](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overnight) is a perfectly idiomatic term for something that is completed much faster than expected (and, of course, something that would be expected to take much longer than one day).

For example: "Popular support for the war crumbled overnight, once the government's deception was revealed".

Comment: +1 And it often has the implication of *while we slept*.

Comment: “An overnight success is ten years in the making.” - Tom Clancy

Comment: Well, thank you, I was thinking about this solution, and once you put it in pretty similar context compared to mine, I think it could fit nicely.

Answer (score 8):

If you want an idiomatic term, you could use *[lickety-split](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lickety-split)*

> With great speed.

*American Heritage*

Answer (score 7):

*In a flash.*

> Also, in a jiffy or second or trice . Quickly, immediately. For
>   example, I'll be with you in a flash, or He said he'd be done in a
>   jiffy, or I'll be off the phone in a second, or I felt a drop or two,
>   and in a trice there was a downpour. The first idiom alludes to a
>   flash of lightning and dates from about 1800. The word jiffy, meaning
>   "a short time," is of uncertain origin and dates from the late 1700s
>   (as does the idiom using it); a second, literally one-sixtieth of a
>   minute, has been used vaguely to mean "a very short time" since the
>   early 1800s; and trice originally meant "a single pull at something"
>   and has been used figuratively since the 1500s.

[in a flash](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+flash)

Answer (score 2):

If overnight isn't fast enough for you,
consider ***[in the blink of an eye](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+blink+of+an+eye)***. 
It can be used in a fairly literal sense:

> There was a huge "boom" and in the blink of an eye the buildings were gone.
>                           <sup>— [source](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+blink+of+an+eye)</sup>

or figuratively:

> There was an empty lot down the road, and, in the blink of an eye,
>   a house appeared.

Comment: Thought about it, this was my first idea, I wanted to see more solutions :) Thanks however.

Answer (score 1):

*Expedite*, and the adjective *expeditious* connote performing tasks faster than usual. Faster than had no effort taken to do so.

The past/completion participle would be used to describe the task that was *expedited*, and the effort taken *expeditious*.

A synonym would be *[accelerate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accelerate)*, and the completion participle *accelerated*.

#### [ex·pe·dite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expedite)  (ĕk′spĭ-dīt′)

tr.v. ex·pe·dit·ed, ex·pe·dit·ing, ex·pe·dites
To speed up the progress of or execute quickly: expedite the review of a legal case; expedite a loan application.

[Latin expedīre, expedīt-, to free from entanglements, make ready; see ped- in Indo-European roots.]
ex′pe·dit′er, ex′pe·di′tor n.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

Answer (score 1):

A common response in this situation would be understatement: **Well, *that* was quick.** with slight emphasis on "that". Since the fact of quickness is what is being commented on, it implies that the quickness was unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

> dramatically fast/quick
>
> unparalleled/unmatched speed
>
> unanticipated haste